# 3D movie on Samsung 120hz HDTV?

Tags: hdtv, 3d-ready

I have a question regarding 3D movies. I was told that 3D movies require at least 120hz display device. Obviously, my computer monitor's max. hz is 60. My Samsung 55'' TV supports 120hz. Can I hook up a desktop to 120hz TV and watch 3D movies on it?

I can't test it because I need to buy glass for 3D, so..I want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at nVidia's [3D vision kit](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_3D_VisionKit_us.html).

read the specifications for the graphics card requirements (for 3D movies, any Geforce 8, 9, 100/200 series will do). ATI has not yet released any equivalent.

contact [nvidia tech support](http://www.nvidia.com/page/support.html) and ask whether your TV is supported, the list may not be upt to date.

Answer (score 1):

Red/Blue 3D should work on any monitor, you only need high speed TVs for [LCD shutter glasses](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/LCD_shutter_glasses).